# Applescript: hiding manipulation of gui when running a gui applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm working on an applescript that clicks menu items in an application menu bar. I'd like to run this script without it displaying the whole process of clicking the target menu item. For example, here's some code below to click the `disable for an hour` menu item in the menu bar for the F.lux application

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Flux"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Flux"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item "Disable for an hour" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

How do I go about preventing the display of the gui manipulation when running the this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. For AppleScript GUI scripting to work the UI elements must be front and key as they would be for the human.